# Input not being added to my mysql server?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

So here I am trying to create a logbook with some simple php.

The problem is that nothing is being added to the database I created. Whenever I check the database I just keep getting an empty dataset after adding and submitting text on the guestbook form.

Can anybody see any problems with my code?

```
<?php
$sql = mysql_connect("localhost" , "root") or die(mysql_error);
mysql_select_db("guestbook" , $sql);

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (name , email) VALUES ('$name' ,      '$email')");
    echo ("Message succesfully added.");
}
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Guestbook</title>
    </head>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"/><br>
        Email: <input type="text" name="email"/><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Post!"/>
    </form>
</html>

<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM message ORDER BY id DESC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))    
{
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Name:</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Message:</td>
        <td><?php echo $row['email'] ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: [owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS))

Comment: You really should do some error checking in that code, if it comes to the mysql functions. You are on a blind flight...

Comment: Please stop using the deprecated mysql extensions

Comment: @ZombieHunter I'm very new to this, sorry for my mistakes but your comment isn't helpful in the slightest.

Comment: What ZombieHunter is saying is that you should be using the [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) objects instead of the older `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `name` is a reserved word in mysql isn't it?

you might have to modify your inset script as follows:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (`name` , email) VALUES ('$name', '$email')");
```

Having said that, your script is WIDE open to an injection attack. You should be using PDO and also verifying data before you go sticking it into an SQL statement. What do you do when your user enters `bob;drop table users;` as his name and your query runs?

Edit: Also, you had a bracket missing.

Edit 2: If you are still getting an error run this and let us know what you see:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO message (`name` , email) VALUES ('$name', '$email')";
echo $sql;
```

There is a good chance you see that one of the variables is empty.

Edit 3:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    if(!empty($name) && !empty($email))
    {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (name , email) VALUES ('$name' ,      '$email')");
        echo ("Message succesfully added.");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "It seems that either name or email was empty, so not inserting data.<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Edit 4 - aka *Goodness me!*
I also noticed that I failed to add the extra bracket to the code that I copied from your question. I have edited it to include it from now on.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['useremail']);

    if(!empty($name) && !empty($email))
    {
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (name , email) VALUES ('$username', '$useremail')");
        echo ("Message succesfully added.");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "It seems that either name or email was empty, so not inserting data.<br>";
    }
}


<html>
    <head>
    <title>Guestbook</title>
    </head>
    <form action="index.php" method="post">
    Name: <input type="text" name="username"/><br>
    Email: <input type="text" name="useremail"/><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Post!"/>
    </form>



?>
// Make sure you stick this </html> at the BOTTOM of you php file.
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm pretty new to php so I'm still learning. I'm not to worried about attacks at the moment as I'm just testing locally for myself but I will definitely make sure its secure if I ever put it live!

Comment: Great, if this answer has solved your problem, please Accept it and we can all move on to the next question that is still open :)

Comment: @Ashmore11: If you don't take care about security now you will likley forget to fix it later.

Comment: Instead I just changed the variable to $fullname but now I'm getting an error code for line 28 (Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/g_book/index.php on line 28) and there is still no data being entered in the database.

Comment: I tried your second edit and this is what I got: INSERT INTO message (fullname , email) VALUES ('', '')

Comment: Bazinga. Can you tell me if you are seeing the `Message succesfully added` echo in your HTML?

Comment: Yes I can still see the Message Succesfully added.

Comment: Ok I tried it again and now this is what I see: INSERT INTO message (fullname , email) VALUES ('hello', 'hello')Message succesfully added.

Comment: Your third edit works but only if the fields are empty. There is still nothing being added to the database and I'm still receiving the error from line 28 I mentioned a few comments earlier. Thanks for all your help @Fluffeh

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (name , email) VALUES ('$name' , '$email'");
```

With

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO message (name , email) VALUES ('$name' , '$email')");
```